# RAM size for Rendering in Eevee

Tags: rendering

Currently I am using 16 GB RAM in my system. If I increase RAM by another 16 GB, whether this will help me to reduce Render time in Eevee (Blender edition 2.9.3.4), if other system specifications remains same?

Comment: I imagine this might depend on what you are trying to render.

Comment: Render time was base on CPU and GPU. Bigger RAM means bigger data that machine can handle, for RAM on GPU it mean bigger texture and polygon. You can check  benchmark data at https://opendata.blender.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your scene fits in your RAM, the amount of RAM doesn't change the render time. It will only change how much data you can load, how much you can chew before it has to use your disk, which is then drastically slower.

What can have an impact on render times with RAM is its clock speed. Faster RAM makes you load and unload that data faster. Especially if you also upgrade from DDR3 to DDR4.
But most likely you are not concerned by this change if you only want to add more RAM stick to what you have: your motherboard can't support both memory type as they have different specs and plugs. And if you use different clock speeds, your motherboard would probably just automatically underclock the faster one and you won't profit of the faster speed.

So basically, the only way to profit of a faster RAM is to change the entire RAM kit, and maybe even your motherboard if the one you have right now doesn't support DDR4 and/or faster clock speed.

THAT BEING SAID:
Unless you need to render heavy scenes, RAM is not the biggest factor in render speed. CPU and GPU are the number one factors. If you want to do GPU rendering primarily, focus on that. But don't ditch the CPU neither, having a somewhat balanced configuration is important : your config is as strong as its weakest link. Even when doing GPU rendering, Blender still uses CPU for some tasks like BVH baking and whatnot.

TL;DR:
If you need speed, you probably want to upgrade your GPU and CPU first.

If you are not comfortable to choose hardware for your needs, don't hesitate to get help on some hardware config forum. There are a lot of people happy to help out and get the best you can afford for your needs.

Comment: The amount of available ram affects the working set size, which in turn affects paging.  If the WS size becomes too large, the program will swap pages and performance will degrade dramatically.

Comment: Damn I forgot about that, good catch!

Comment: Though I wonder how this works particularly in Eevee? AFAIK Eevee is an OpenGl render done by the GPU, yet the RAM is also used, but what is being charged to either VRAM or RAM?

Comment: The rendering itself is only ever going to use the video ram, so it's either you have enough video ram or you don't.  But the modifiers are going to use system ram, and could potentially fall back to swap drive.